# Tracking file SLAs with AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am receiving 10 files from upstream sources dropped to an S3 location. All 10 of them need to be received by a certain SLA, and if that SLA is breached I need to escalate using eventing mechanism.
Is there a feature in S3, or integration with another AWS service that can help with implementation of this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may work:

- Establish the SLA with your upstream systems (Lets say everyday between 1PM-1:30PM)
- Trigger a Step Function that is invoked using CloudWatch events at 1 PM. Keep checking if the files have arrived in the Step Function (every 5 minutes)
- If files have not arrived by 1:30PM, trigger an event that emails you saying files have not arrived and end the step function execution.
- If files have arrived by 1:30PM, end the step function execution.

OR

- Establish the SLA with your upstream systems (Lets say everyday between 1PM-1:30PM)
- Trigger a Lambda Function that is invoked using CloudWatch events at 1:35 PM.
- If files have not arrived, trigger an event that emails you saying files have not arrived.
- If files have arrived, do nothing.